# How to import multiple csv files into AWS RDS and test it correctly

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-rds

On our current project we'll need to import several csv files stored on S3 into AWS RDS (it will be MySQL engine most likely).

What is the best way to achieve this considering that we want to include cvs filename and upload timestamp in a target table as well? How to test it properly?

I found the following approach in the docs - [Loading Data into an Amazon Aurora MySQL DB Cluster from Text Files in an Amazon S3 Bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.LoadFromS3.html). But I cannot test it at the moment. I'll really appreciate if you can share your experience with RDS

Comment: What do you mean by "But I cannot test it at the moment"?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein infrastructure wasn't yet provisioned for us. We are in the process of planning our possible solution